# Changing background bitmap in Wix ExitDialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to add a checkbox to the ExitDialog to launch an application after install. I've done that without problems but then I ran into the same problem as everybody else - that checkboxes and radio buttons do not support transparency so the checkbox I've shown has an ugly gray frame around it because of the background bitmap.

I've seen several suggestions about how to make my own exit dialog, resizing the checkbox in combination with a text label. My idea was to show a different and more narrow background bitmap in the ExitDialog (and only that).

In the source I can see that the bitmap is controlled by:

```
<Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogBitmap)" />
```

My question is how to replace the default bitmap with another bitmap for this dialog only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` attribute of the `Control` element with a type of `Bitmap` references the `Id` attribute of a `Binary` element pointing to a raster graphics image file. If you look at the source code for the UIExtension (which you are using I assume), you will find out that `!(loc.ExitDialogBitmap)` resolves to `WixUI_Bmp_Dialog`. So you simply have to create a `Binary` element with its `Id` attribute set to `WixUI_Bmp_Dialog`. Unfortunately this `Id` is used by 7 other Dialogs in the UIExtension.

Fortunately the localization strings for each of these bitmaps is overridable. So you just have to create a `String` element in your localization file like this:

```
<String Id="ExitDialogBitmap">MyOwnExitBitmap</String>
```

and a corresponding Binary element:

```
<Binary Id="MyOwnExitBitmap" SourceFile="myOwnExit.bmp" />
```

Comment: Thanks - I got the bitmap replaced. But my narrow bitmap (narrow to avoid overlapping the checkbox) is stretched to fill out the entire bitmap control and hence looks awfull.
So I have an additional question: Is it possible to change the Width of the bitmap control?

Comment: You won't be able to change it like the picture in the solution above, because the width is fixed in the sourcecode. You could however simply copy the source code for that dialog and create a dialog based on that in which the width is specified by you. Then you have to sequence it accordingly. But if you go that route, you might as well do the whole UI yourself, without the extension...

Comment: Fixed it :-) 
I made a 32 bit bitmap with the normal size and with transparency in the right side where the text and checkbox is shown.